# Identify groups with an absent value of interest

Tags: r

I am interested in knowing which groups in my data do not have the value 'N'.

My data are as follows:

```
group value
A     Y
A     Y
A     Y
B     Y
B     N
B     N
C     Y
C     Y
C     N
D     Y
D     Y
D     Y
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
group
A
D
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another base R version of `subset` using `ave`

```
> unique(subset(df, !ave(value == "N", group, FUN = any), select = group))
   group
1      A
10     D
```

---

or `subset` + `aggregate`

```
> subset(aggregate(. ~ group, df, FUN = function(x) any(x == "N")), !value, select = group)
  group
1     A
4     D
```

---

or `tapply` + `Filter`

```
> with(df, Filter(isTRUE, tapply(value == "N", group, Negate(any))))
   A    D
TRUE TRUE
```

---

or `unstack` + `colSums` + `Filter`

```
> Filter(isTRUE, colSums(unstack(rev(df)) == "N") == 0)
   A    D
TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Another Base R:

```
 names(which(table(df)[,"N"] == 0))
[1] "A" "D"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just `subset` with `%in%` to create a logical vector that returns TRUE where 'N' occurs, get the corresponding 'group', create another logical vector with group and negate (`!`) so that that this returns only group having no 'N'

```
unique( subset(df1, !group %in% group[value %in% 'N'], select = group))
#   group
#1      A
#10     D
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
df1 %>%
   distinct %>%
   filter(!group %in% group[value %in% 'N']) %>%
   select(group)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "D", "D", "D"), value = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", 
"Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```